# Can't connect to mysql server on 'public ip address' (10060)

Tags: server, mysql

I was following this guide to setup a mysql server on my ubuntu machine (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04).
But when I tried to connect to the database from my local machine with mysql workbench I keep running into the problem `can't connect to mysql server on 'public ip' (10060)`

I tried a different version of mysql workbench because the version `8.0.28` gave the error `can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost'` when specifying an IP address. I also changed the `bind addressess` in the `/etc/mysql/mysqld.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to `0.0.0.0` instead of the default `127.0.0.1`. I also allowed remote access in my firewall by executing `ufw allow 3306`
This is an overview of the users

```
+------------------+---------------+
| user             | host          |
+------------------+---------------+
| david            | %             |
| fimetsu          | public-ip-address |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost     |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost     |
| mysql.session    | localhost     |
| mysql.sys        | localhost     |
| root             | localhost     |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Im not sure if the problem is with that my server has no access or that my users need specific access i've tried connecting with user fimetsu and david but both don't seem to work
All help is greatly appreciated!

#### EDIT

In mysql workbench I also try to connect to my mysql server with public ip. the same as reference to user fimetsu. Again I'm not sure what IP to use to connect to this server. All help is greatly appreciated!